# VueJS dont display input value if its 0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an input field that gets pre-populated from my DB, but I won't want it to be pre-filled if the value is **0**

Eg:

```
<input v-model="price" type="text">
```

If

```
  data: {
 price: 0
}
```

I don't want my input field to display 0, I know that I can do stuff like `:disabled="price == 0"` but this will hide the whole input field, I just don't want to display the value if its 0

Comment: What about programatically changing the value from 0 to "" in the model? Would that work?

Comment: you could try something like this: `price !== 0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change price to empty string when it's 0:

```
created() {
    //since 0 is considered false it will put an empty string in case priceFromDB is 0
    this.price = priceFromDB || ''
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you want to always have empty input when value of price is `0`, even if user type It manually.If that's true, something like this should work for you:

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="price" @keyup="trackChange">
</div>
```

JS:

```
const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    price: 0
  },

  methods: {
    trackChange() {
      this.price = parseInt(this.price) === 0  ? null : this.price
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.trackChange()
  }


})
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/sihuyotuto/edit?html,js,output